# Java Extracting Text Between Tags and Attributes

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract text between particular tags and attributes. For now, I tried to extract for tags. I am reading a ".gexf" file which has XML data inside. Then I am saving this data as a string. Then I am trying to extract text between "nodes" tag. Here is my code so far:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    private static String filePath = "src/babel.gexf";

    public String readFile(String filePath) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append("\n");
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
    }

    public void getNodesContent(String content) throws IOException {
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<nodes>(\\w+)</nodes>", Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
        Main m = new Main();
        String result = m.readFile(filePath);
        m.getNodesContent(result);
    }
}
```

In the code above, I don't get any result. When I try it with sample string like "My string", I get the result. Link of the gexf (since it is too long, I had to upload it) file: 
https://files.fm/u/qag5ykrx

Comment: *FYI:* If you want to read entire file into a `String`, you should just do `return new String(Files.readAllBytes​(Paths.get(filePath)));`

Comment: Since it’s just XML - why not use a XML parser and maybe xpath

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: And a quick google (since I had no idea what gefx was) shows there are a number libraries available for it - maybe consider one of those

Comment: I tried with XPath class but I also stucked there. Do you think it is the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think placing the entire file contents into a single string is such a great idea but then I suppose that would depend upon the amount of content within the file. If it's a lot of content then I would read in that content a little differently. It would of been nice to see a fictitious example of what the file contains.

I suppose you can try this little method. The heart of it utilizes a regular expression (RegEx) along with **Pattern/Matcher** to retrieve the desired substring from between tags.

It is important to read the doc's with the method:

```
/**
 * This method will retrieve a string contained between string tags. You
 * specify what the starting and ending tags are within the startTag and
 * endTag parameters. It is you who determines what the start and end tags
 * are to be which can be any strings.<br><br>
 *
 * @param inputString (String) Any string to process.<br>
 *
 * @param startTag (String) The Start Tag String or String. Data content retrieved
 * will be directly after this tag.<br><br>
 *
 * The supplied Start Tag criteria can contain a single special wildcard tag
 * (~*~) providing you also place something like the closing chevron (>)
 * for an HTML tag after the wildcard tag, for example:<pre>
 *
 * If we have a string which looks like this:
 *      {@code
 *      "<p style=\"padding-left:40px;\">Hello</p>"
 *      }
 *      (Note: to pass double quote marks in a string they must be excaped)
 *
 * and we want to use this method to extract the word "Hello" from between the
 * two HTML tags then your Start Tag can be supplied as "&lt;p~*~&gt;" and of course
 * your End Tag can be "&lt;/p&gt;". The "&lt;p~*~&gt;" would be the same as supplying
 * "&lt;p style=\"padding-left:40px;\"&gt;". Anything between the characters &lt;p and
 * the supplied close chevron (&gt;) is taken into consideration. This allows for
 * contents extraction regardless of what HTML attributes are attached to the
 * tag. The use of a wildcard tag (~*~) is also allowed in a supplied End
 * Tag.</pre><br>
 *
 * The wildcard is used as a special tag so that strings that actually
 * contain asterisks (*) can be processed as regular asterisks.<br>
 *
 * @param endTag (String) The End Tag or String. Data content retrieval will
 * end just before this Tag is reached.<br>
 *
 * The supplied End Tag criteria can contain a single special wildcard tag
 * (~*~) providing you also place something like the closing chevron (&gt;)
 * for an HTML tag after the wildcard tag, for example:<pre>
 *
 * If we have a string which looks like this:
 *      {@code
 *      "<p style=\"padding-left:40px;\">Hello</p>"
 *      }
 *      (Note: to pass double quote marks in a string they must be excaped)
 *
 * and we want to use this method to extract the word "Hello" from between the
 * two HTML tags then your Start Tag can be supplied as "&lt;p style=\"padding-left:40px;\"&gt;"
 * and your End Tag can be "&lt;/~*~&gt;". The "&lt;/~*~&gt;" would be the same as supplying
 * "&lt;/p&gt;". Anything between the characters &lt;/ and the supplied close chevron (&gt;)
 * is taken into consideration. This allows for contents extraction regardless of what the
 * HTML tag might be. The use of a wildcard tag (~*~) is also allowed in a supplied Start Tag.</pre><br>
 *
 * The wildcard is used as a special tag so that strings that actually
 * contain asterisks (*) can be processed as regular asterisks.<br>
 *
 * @param trimFoundData (Optional - Boolean - Default is true) By default
 * all retrieved data is trimmed of leading and trailing white-spaces. If
 * you do not want this then supply false to this optional parameter.
 *
 * @return (1D String Array) If there is more than one pair of Start and End
 * Tags contained within the supplied input String then each set is placed
 * into the Array separately.<br>
 *
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if any supplied method String argument
 * is Null ("").
 */
public static String[] getBetweenTags(String inputString, String startTag,
        String endTag, boolean... trimFoundData) {
    if (inputString == null || inputString.equals("") || startTag == null ||
            startTag.equals("") || endTag == null || endTag.equals("")) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("\ngetBetweenTags() Method Error! - "
                + "A supplied method argument contains Null (\"\")!\n"
                + "Supplied Method Arguments:\n"
                + "==========================\n"
                + "inputString = \"" + inputString + "\"\n"
                + "startTag = \"" + startTag + "\"\n"
                + "endTag = \"" + endTag + "\"\n");
    }

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean trimFound = true;
    if (trimFoundData.length > 0) {
        trimFound = trimFoundData[0];
    }

    Matcher matcher;
    if (startTag.contains("~*~") || endTag.contains("~*~")) {
        startTag = startTag.replace("~*~", ".*?");
        endTag = endTag.replace("~*~", ".*?");
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?iu)" + startTag + "(.*?)" + endTag);
        matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);
    } else {
        String regexString = Pattern.quote(startTag) + "(?s)(.*?)" + Pattern.quote(endTag);
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?iu)" + regexString);
        matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);
    }

    while (matcher.find()) {
        String match = matcher.group(1);
        if (trimFound) {
            match = match.trim();
        }
        list.add(match);
    }
    return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind respond! This probably will work. I also solved my problem by using XPath. XPath seems a better way to do that. But I will also try this solution and see what is gonna happen!

Answer (score 0):

Without a sample of the file I can only suggest so much. On the contrary, what I can tell you is that you can get the substring of that text using a tag search loop. Here is an example:

```
String s = "<a>test</a><b>list</b><a>class</a>";
int start = 0,  end = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < s.toCharArray().length-1; i++){
    if(s.toCharArray()[i] == '<' && s.toCharArray()[i+1] == 'a' &&     s.toCharArray()[i+2] == '>'){
        start = i+3;
        for(int j = start+3; j < s.toCharArray().length-1; j++){
            if(s.toCharArray()[j] == '<' && s.toCharArray()[j+1] == '/' && s.toCharArray()[j+2] == 'a' && s.toCharArray()[j+3] == '>'){
                end = j;
                System.out.println(s.substring(start, end));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code will search string s for the tag and then start where it found that and continue until it finds the closing a tag. then it uses those two positions to create a substring of the string which is the text between the two tags. You can stack as many of these tag searches as you want. Here is an example of a 2 tag search:

```
String s = "<a>test</a><b>list</b><a>class</a>";
int start = 0,  end = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < s.toCharArray().length-1; i++){
    if((s.toCharArray()[i] == '<' && s.toCharArray()[i+1] == 'a' && s.toCharArray()[i+2] == '>') ||
            (s.toCharArray()[i] == '<' && s.toCharArray()[i+1] == 'b' && s.toCharArray()[i+2] == '>')){
        start = i+3;
        for(int j = start+3; j < s.toCharArray().length-1; j++){
            if((s.toCharArray()[j] == '<' && s.toCharArray()[j+1] == '/' && s.toCharArray()[j+2] == 'a' && s.toCharArray()[j+3] == '>') || 
                    (s.toCharArray()[j] == '<' && s.toCharArray()[j+1] == '/' && s.toCharArray()[j+2] == 'b' && s.toCharArray()[j+3] == '>')){
                end = j;
                System.out.println(s.substring(start, end));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only difference is that i've added clauses to the if statements to also get the text between b tags. This system is extreemly versatile and I think you'll fund an abundance of use for it.